# Chess Tournament Games logic

Tags: combinatorics

Ten people are playing in a chess tournament.
Let w(1), w(2), until w(10) denote the number of games player 1 through 10 has won.
Let l(1), l(2), until l(10) denote the number of games player 1 through 10 has lost.
Prove that w(1)^2 + w(2)^2 + .. + w(10)^2 = l(1)^2 + l(2)^2 + .. + l(10)^2

Comment: Hm , assume player $1$ wins against players $2,3,4$ , the other games are draw. Then, the equality would be $3^2=1^2+1^2+1^2$ , obviously wrong.

Comment: @Peter You need to assume draws are impossible. Unlike normal chess, ties are broken by, say, penalty kicks in this tournament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two sums $\sum_{x=1}^{10}w(x)^2$ and $\sum_{x=1}^{10}l(x)^2$ are equal, their difference is $0$.
Proof:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=1}^{10}w(x)^2-\sum_{x=1}^{10}l(x)^2\\
=&\sum_{x=1}^{10}(w(x)^2-l(x)^2)\\
=&\sum_{x=1}^{10}(w(x)+l(x))\times (w(x)-l(x))\\
=&\sum_{x=1}^{10}(9\times (w(x)-l(x)))\\
=&9\times\sum_{x=1}^{10}(w(x)-l(x))\\
=&0\end{align}
since the total number of wins among the $10$ players  equals the total number of losses among the $10$ players.

Comment: Didn't expect such an easy solution ! Well done ! (+1)